# Laravel php controller for pdf

Tags: php, laravel

I am wondering what to write in my laravel controller to allow me work with a pdf document posted from the front end by an AJAX request. I have found code online to check if an image is uploaded, but anyone have an idea what I need to do if it's a pdf document.

Please see my code below.

```
public function postUpload() {
    $file = Input::file('image');
    do something here.....     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An example from [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files):

```
public function postUpload(Request $request) {
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        do something here.....
    }
}
```

To check if file is PDF, use validation rules, like:

```
$rules  = [
    "file" => "mimes:pdf"
]
```